# Make a node project directory and SVN repository

Tags: node.js, svn

I have a node app running on production server `~/nodeapp`
I am trying to turn `/username/nodeapp` to an SVN repos

Since this is running on live server!! here are the steps I took

**Create a repo**

```
svnadmin create ~/nodeapp.svn
```

**Set permission**

```
vi ~/nodeapp.svn/conf/svnserve.conf
and add the following:

anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

**Import ~/nodeapp into the ~/nodeapp.svn**

```
svn import ~/nodeapp file:///home/nodeapp.svn
```

**Finally Rename Folders**

```
mv ~/nodeapp ~/nodeapp.bak
mv ~/nodeapp.svn ~/nodeapp
```

nodeapp should now be under version control.. however pages are not loading
when I

```
cd ~/nodeapp && node app.js
```

What am I doing wrong. Why is node under SVN Repo not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion repositories are nothing like git repositories, which it looks like you're trying to emulate here. You cannot run your Node app directly out of the Subversion repository.

Instead, you need to have your repository elsewhere (on the filesystem or on a Subversion server elsewhere). Commit your code to the repository and check out a working copy to `~/nodeapp` for your application to run.

You really need to read the Subversion manual, and pay special attention to the ["Version Control the Subversion Way" section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html). Also, the FAQ entry about [running a website with the code managed by Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update) may be helpful